# How do I format my GET request to the Spotify Web API in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify

I'm new to working with APIs. I'm trying to create a script that will output the tracks of a public playlist from Spotify. I have hit a roadblock at an early stage: **I'm unsure how exactly to format my GET request** to retrieve the tracks of the playlist in question and where I put the OAuth access token. My current attempt returns a 401 status code.

**What I've done so far:**

- I have created an App on the Spotify Developers website dashboard.
- I have saved client_id and client_secret from the dashboard into a script ("spotifysecrets.py").
- I have run the following code in my main script:

```
import requests

from spotifysecrets import client_id as cid, client_secret as cs

AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

token_req = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": cid,
    "client_secret": cs
    })

access_token = token_req.json()["access_token"]
```

Everything appears to have worked fine so far. The problem occurs in the next step.

- Having obtained the token, I am getting a **401 error** when trying to make my tracks request. The code I have written is as follows:

```
pl_id = "…"  # I have elided the actual playlist ID for the purposes of this question
tracks = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{}/tracks".format(pl_id)
songs_req = requests.get(tracks, {
    "Authorization": "Basic {}".format(access_token)
    })
```

### Edit

I have tried using

```
songs_req = requests.get(tracks, headers={
    "Authorization": "Basic {}".format(access_token)
    })
```

instead but this gives a 400 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the api and I believe you have a syntax error:

```
songs_req = requests.get(tracks, {
    "Authorization": "Basic {}".format(access_token)
    })
```

should be:

```
songs_req = requests.get(tracks, {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(access_token)
    })
```